# Arquillian TomEE embedded test with web sockets

Tags: websocket, spock, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

I' trying to write a test of a serverendpoint using websockets in an arquillian test. I get an error saying

`Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 404.`

When deploying, I get a warning in the log of the tomee:

```
WARNING: Can't set TomEE ServerEndpointConfig$Configurator
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: defaultImpl
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.forceEEServerEndpointConfigurator(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:338)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.<init>(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:284)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.start(Container.java:293)
    ....
```

The endpoints are defined like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/games")
public class GameEndPoint {

    @Inject
    GameManager gameManager;
    @Inject
    private GameSessionHandler sessionHandler;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(String payload, Session session) {
    }
}

@ClientEndpoint
public class SocketClient {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Session %s close because of %s",     session.getId(), closeReason));
    }

    public void openConnection(URL url) {//URL injected arquillian resource, where url is for http connection..
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        try {
            URI uri = URI.create(url.toString().replace("http", "ws") + "games");
            container.connectToServer(this, uri);
        } catch (DeploymentException | IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My test is written in spock, which fails in setup

```
@RunWith(ArquillianSputnik)
class GameServiceSocketIT extends Specification {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive archive() {
        return createDeployment();//shrinkwrap stuff
    }
    @ArquillianResource
    URL url;
    @Inject
    SocketClient client;

    def Game currentGame = null

    def setup() { // run before every feature method
        client.openConnection(url);
    }

    def 'init new game' () {
        given: 'blabla'
            blabla
        when: 'blalba'
            blabla
        then: 'blabla'
            blablabla...
    }
}
```

My pom dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.spock</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-spock-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For Arquillian Integration tests in TOMEE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-container-jdk-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Edit:

my createDeployment method:

```
return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"))
            .addPackages(true, Filters.exclude(".*IT.class"), "engine")
            .addPackages(true, Filters.exclude(".*IT.class"), "socket")
            .addPackages(true, Filters.exclude(".*IT.class"), "persistence");
```

Comment: It looks like something may be missing in your microdepoyment for the deployment to happen correctly.

Comment: yes, so it seems. but the question is what?

Comment: seems that adding the dependency `org.apache.tomcat:tomcat7-websocket` fixes the problem, But I do not get cdi injection in my serverendpoint..

Comment: I don't see any cdi annotations on that class that would trigger cdi to pick it up as a cdi bean

Comment: do I need to annotate the class with @stateless or similar..?

Comment: Yes, you need some ejb or cdi annotation in the class

Comment: well..still does'nt work..

Comment: Same error? Do you have a beans.xml file in the bundle?

Comment: yup..an empty one added with shrinkwrap in the createDeployment method

Comment: I think a good place to see is https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/websocket you can see several websockets examples with its own Arquillian test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

with the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.59</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Fixes the problem and I now get the client to connect to my server, hower now I'm having problems with CDI injection in my `ServerEndPoint`. That seems to be another issue..

Comment: I will suggest running managed/remote adapter instead of the embedded once. And see what's happening and depending on the result we will able to do a diagnostic :)